# Get info about whether gstreamer is recieving any packet

Tags: embedded-linux, gstreamer

My application was to have a audio streaming application in a multicast group. Its like a push to talk radio. When someone push the button audio gets transmitted. I am using gstreamer for streaming audio. Is there any way that i can know whether someone is talking at present or not.

When someone presses the button to talk i need to inform him that already someone else is talking or not.

Is there any gstreamer api to know that or is there any other way for knowing it.

Edit:
To understand my question well i will describe a use case.

Consider 4 USERS are there in a multicast group.

- USER1 presses the PTT button and starts talking
- At this time if any one say USER2 presses PTT button i need to inform
  USER2 that USER1 is already
    talking (atleast that someone else is talking).
- Also I need to inform USER1 that USER2 has now pressed PTT button.

Is there any api in gstreamer with which i can get these information

1) Whether someone else is streaming or not in that multicast group?

2) Retrieve info about the streaming user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing built in to GStreamer that will give you a yes/no answer to if someone else is broadcasting. However, it is possible to make gstreamer notify your application every time it gets a udp packet. You might be able to use this information for what you are trying to do.

First, put a tee directly after the udpsrc and attach a fakesink to the tee. Then attach a signal handler to the fake sinks's handoff signal and set the signal-handoffs property to true.

The problem with this approach is that it still does not guarantee someone else is not sending -- only that you have not received anything from them YET. 
Ineviably you will end up crossing streams at some point leaving you with a giant marshmallowy StayPuff mess.

My recommendation is to not use udpsrc and udpsink. They are toys not good for anything but the simplest of use cases.

Instead, Send and receive the multicast packets yourself along with a little header on each packet saying who it is from. When you receive the packet, strip the header and use appsrc to push the stream to the audio player.

If you really want to use gstreamer all the way from the top to the bottom, you will need to creat a custom muxer that adds user info onto packets before going to the udpsink and a custom demuxer that can select a single stream if more than one person is talking at the same time.

Making custom elements is doable, but can be a lot of trouble if you have never worked with glib gobjects before.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then using the gstreamer to notify, why don’t you use the button press count to check if any one is talking or not instead ?

Hope that helps.